# Spatially merging NetCDF climate grids?

Tags: python, merge, netcdf, climate, climate-data-operators

I'm currently working with a large number of CF-compliant NetCDF climate grids with global coverage that are organized as tiles across a file structure pertaining to particular "variables" and "years" (e.g. `precipitation-year1950-001.nc`, `precipitation-year1961-125.nc`, `tmax-year2008-650.nc`, etc.). They're currently organized in a sensible file structure (:project/variable/year/files.nc)

For each variable*year, I would like to spatially merge the tiles (similar in call to `gdal_merge outputfile.tif /path/to/data/*.tif`) using a walking method and I'm wondering what would be the most efficient/reliable way of doing so.

From my research, two (labour-intensive) methods come to mind:

1. Performing a walking loop in BASH that calls the Climate Data Operators ([CDO](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/wiki/)) function `mergegrid`. Since `mergegrid` can only accept two input files for each output, even if I were to merge them efficiently, I would need to call it > 400x for each variable*year.
2. Performing a walking loop in Python with the `NetCDF4` and `NumPy` libraries that creates an empty array the size of the the Earth, which reads each NetCDF to an `np.array` and writes it out to the new NetCDF, appends the metadata, and iterates through the variables*years.

Ideally, I need a method that is easily replicated after I've written the function out and if I can stay in Python3, that would be great. What I would like to know is **which is the better way of merging lots of nested NetCDF data or is there another method/modules that I haven't come across that would be better at performing large spatial merges of NetCDF data**.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/merge.html

Comment: Funny enough, I've been gradually moving towards rioxarray in a few other projects and have raised a few issues there in the past. Thanks for building such a great library!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some reading around and came across obscure CDO documentation for the `collgrid` function. With that, I was able to finally perform this series of merges in python by walking through files and performing a `subprocess` call to CDO using something similar to the following:

```
#!/bin/python3

import os
import subprocess

source = "/path/to/source"
destination = "path/to/destination"

nc_filenames = []
nc_f = {}
for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(source):
    print(dirpath)
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".nc"):
            nc_filenames.append(f)
            nc_f[f] = os.path.join(dirpath, f)

filegroups = []
for f in nc_filenames:
    filegroups.append('-'.join('.'.join(f.split('.')[0:-1]).split('-')[0:-1]))

tiles = range(1000)

for group in set(filegroups):
    if group is not '':
        infiles = []
        output = str(group) + ".nc"
        for i in tiles:
            file = str(group) + '-' + i + ".nc"
            infiles.append(nc_f[file])
        inputs = ' '.join(infiles)
        outputs = os.path.join(destination, output)
        subprocess.call(["cdo", "-z", "zip", "collgrid", inputs, outputs])
```

Comment: so in other words you still need a loop? I don't understand why cat can handle many files and mergegrid can't, maybe using the r package raster and create a raster stack might work better.